# std::endl, is there an equivalent in Python? (return + flush)

Tags: python, c++, endl

In C++, `std::endl` is used to add a return and flush the string.
In Python, there is no need to use this special functionality, except for specific uses.

One of the uses that may justify its use is when the output is redirected to a file, for example:

```py
outfile = open("output_file.txt", 'a')
sys.stdout = outfile
print("Something")
```

In this case, the file does not show its content unless the file is closed (`outfile.close()`) or manually flushed (`outfile.flush()`).

If an equivalent of `std::endl` from C++ exists in Python, it could both write the line and flush the file.

I doubt that this functionality exists, but I ask this question to be sure.

Thanks :)

Comment: in pyhton `print` itself calls new line after displaying the output

Comment: you could always bind one yourself. `endl = lamda: print('\n')`. A simple `print()` would do as well.

Comment: You've rejected two solutions without giving good reasons. Well, sort of: `endl` also flushes, which you're not considering.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I suspect that this is the case of an attempt to literally translate C++ code to Python, one statement at a time. Such an experiment rarely succeeds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.linesep` is the platform-dependent line separator. If you want something shorter, you can give it an alias when you import it, e.g.:

```py
from os import linesep as endl
```